# Cypress: process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I made a simple Cypress test for a basic React app. Checking wether `<div>` with `id` `container` exist, but it fails. What is wrong? I am newbie with Cypress.

Watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ajwAkZDbwo

```
const cypress = require("cypress")

describe("renders the home page", () => {
    it("renders  correctly", () => {
        cypress.visit("/")
        cy.get("#container").should("exist")
    })
})
```

```js
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div id="container"></div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically the import of "cypress" that's giving the error.

You don't need to import it, it's set up globally.

In fact there's two globals

- `cy` used to define commands like `cy.visit()`
- `Cypress` which gives you access to utilities like `Cypress.config('baseUrl')`

```js
// const cypress = require("cypress")  -- don't need this

describe("renders the home page", () => {
    it("renders  correctly", () => {
        // cypress.visit("/")  
        cy.visit("/")
        cy.get("#container").should("exist")
    })
})
```

You should also know that `cy.get("#container").should("exist")` can also be done by just `cy.get("#container")`.

The `cy.get()` command has a built-in existence check, e.g if you used `cy.get("#container2")` on your app it would fail the test because `"#container2"` does not exist.

Comment: OMG, thanks.  In my situation, once I removed that line, which I only added because of errors for all my custom commands and cy() functions, I had to explicitly define a global cypress variable in my commands.js